# How to Edit records using href url to retrieve the record

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

When I click the Edit button on any record using`<a href`, i would like to get the data from the url and allow editing of that record, using `$_GET` how do i pass the value to my SQL query to retrieve the record?

Any help will be appreciated.

```
<?php
include("../include/connect.php");
$gid = (empty($_GET['cu_id']));
if (isset($_POST['cu_id'])) {
$id = $_POST['cu_id'];
}
if (isset($_POST['cu_name'])) {
$customer = $_POST['cu_name'];
}
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
$email = $_POST['email'];
}
if (isset($_POST['phone'])){
$phone =($_POST['phone']);
}
if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
$pass =$_POST['password'];
}
if (isset($_POST['coun_id'])) {
$counter =$_POST['coun_id'];
}
if (isset($_POST['card_id'])){
$card_id =$_POST['card_id'];
}
$q=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM customer WHERE cu_id ='".$gid."'")or 
die (mysqli_error());
$r = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($q);
if (isset($_REQUEST['edit']) AND $_REQUEST['edit'] == 'customer') {
echo "
<form action= '' method ='post' class'input_type'>
<input type='text' name='cu_name' value='".$r['cu_name']."'/><br/>
<input type='text' name='email' value='".$r['email']."'/><br/>
<input type='text' name='phone' value='".$r['phone']."'/><br/>
<input type='text' name='password' value='".$r['password']."'/><br/>
<input type='text' name='coun_id' value='".$r['coun_id']."'/><br/>
<input type='text' name='card_id' value='".$r['card_id']."'/><br/>
<input type='submit' value='save edit' id='sends'/><br/>
<input type='hidden' name='cu_id' value='".$gid."'/><br/>
<input type='hidden' name='edit' value='customer'/><br/>
</form>";
}
/* query */
$query=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM customer order by cu_id desc")or 
die (mysqli_error());
echo "<center>";
echo"<table width='40%' border='1'cellpadding='5' id='ttb' >
<tr>
<th>cu id </th>
<th>cu name</th> 
<th>email </th>
<th>phone </th>
<th> coun id</th>
<th> card id</th>
<th> update</th>
<th>delete</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
echo "
<tr>
<td>".$row['cu_id']."</td>
<td>".$row['cu_name']."</td>
<td>".$row['email']." </td>
<td>".$row['phone']." </td>
<td> ".$row['coun_id']."</td>
<td> ".$row['card_id']."</td>
<td>
<a href='cucontrol.php?edit&id=".$row['cu_id']."'>edit</a></td>
</td>
<td><a href='cucontrol.php?delete=user&id=".$row['cu_id']."'>delete</a></td>
</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
echo "</center>";
echo "</div>";
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: There is a rumor floating around the internet that indenting code makes it readable. Have you heard of that rumor?

Comment: If you are going to ask a bunch of professionals to spend their valuable time  on a problem you're having, then don't just dump your unreadable code and copy paste the same text 5 times. Please format your code properly and read the [ask]. After that we might be able to help you.

Comment: I downvoted, and voted to close, because it appears you made no effort at all with your question. Your question text is repeated 3x, but even so I don't know what your question is.  Please visit the help centre and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

on your **cucontrol.php** get the id from the URL using `$_GET['cu_id']` and pass it to your SQL query to retrieve the record `where cu_id = $id_from_url`. you will have to echo the records in a form to allow the user to change the information and `POST`it back to the page, you'll then need to get the new details from the post and use the `UPDATE` in your SQL query to update the record.

**cucontrol.php**

```
if(isset($_GET['cu_id'])){

$id = $_GET['cu_id'];

 $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM customer WHERE cu_id = '$id'") or 
 die (mysqli_error($query));
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

 echo '
   <form method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value ="'.$row['cu_id'].'"/>
   <input type="text" name="c_name" value ="'.$row['cu_name'].'"/>
   <input type="text" name="c_email" value ="'.$row['email'].'"/>
   <input type="text" name="c_phone" value ="'.$row['phone'].'"/>
   <input type="text" name="coun_id" value ="'.$row['cu_id'].'"/> //delete this line if they cant edit it
   <input type="text" name="card_id" value ="'.$row['cu_id'].'"/>//delete this line if they cant edit it
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value ="Send"/>
   </form>';

  }


   if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 $id = $_POST['id'];
 $c_name = $_POST['c_name'];
 $c_email = $_POST['c_email'];
 $c_phone = $_POST['c_phone'];

 $query = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE customer SET cu_name = '$c_name',
 email = '$c_email', phone = '$c_phone' WHERE cu_id = '$id'") or 
 die (mysqli_error($query));

 if ($query){

  echo '<script>alert("Update Successful!");</script>';

        }

     }
```

Comment: i made a slight mistake change `UPDATE customers` to `UPDATE customer` your table name is customer not customers